# Switch author and title in beamer bibliography

Tags: beamer, bibtex, bibliographies

When I include references in a `beamer` frame, the author is printed first, followed by the title, followed by the journal/note. I'm using bibtex for referencing.

```
    \bibliographystyle{unsrt}
    \bibliography{report.bib}
```

The output looks as follows:
[image: bibliography]

How can I make the title appear on top, followed by the author underneath?

I have been looking at [beamerbaselocalstructure.sty](http://www.tex.ac.uk/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/beamerbaselocalstructure.sty) to redefine the newblock definition, but have been unsuccessful so far.

Here's sample code that results in the output above (although it uses inline bibitems instead of bibtex). I do not want to switch the author and title field in the bibtex file.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

    \begin{thebibliography}{10}
        \bibitem{patchdroid} Collin Mulliner, Jon Oberheide, William Robertson, and Engin Kirda. \newblock  Scalable Third-Party Security Patches for Android Devices. \newblock In \textit{Proceedings of the 29th Annual Computer Security Applications Conference}, pages 259--268. ACM, 20143.
    \end{thebibliography}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I've added the MWE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to redefine `\beamer@newblock` so that the text in the author block is saved and then later used after the title block. I used the definition of the command in `beamerbaselocalstructure.sty` (Till Tantau, Vedran Miletić) as the starting point for my modifications. Note that the `bibliography entry author` template is now used for the title and the title template is used for the authors.

Anyone with better LaTeX skills is welcome to improve the solution.

[image: Result of running the code]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{xparse}
\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand\beamer@newblock{u{\newblock}}{%
  \def\newblock{%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{bibliography entry title}%
    \usebeamerfont{bibliography entry title}%
    \usebeamertemplate{bibliography entry author}%
    \def\newblock{%
      \usebeamercolor[fg]{bibliography entry author}%
      \usebeamerfont{bibliography entry author}%
      \usebeamertemplate{bibliography entry title}%
      #1%
      \usebeamercolor[fg]{bibliography entry location}%
      \usebeamerfont{bibliography entry location}%
      \usebeamertemplate{bibliography entry location}%
      \def\newblock{%
        \usebeamercolor[fg]{bibliography entry note}%
        \usebeamerfont{bibliography entry note}%
        \usebeamertemplate{bibliography entry note}}}}%
  \leavevmode\setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{}\ht\beamer@tempbox=1.5em\box\beamer@tempbox\newblock}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

    \begin{thebibliography}{10}
        \bibitem{patchdroid} Collin Mulliner, Jon Oberheide, William Robertson, and Engin Kirda. \newblock  Scalable Third-Party Security Patches for Android Devices. \newblock In \textit{Proceedings of the 29th Annual Computer Security Applications Conference}, pages 259--268. ACM, 20143.
    \end{thebibliography}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried switching the whole block for title and author, but didn't  realize I only had to switch the color and font parts. Many thanks!